# "Invalid launch options: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]" while trying to call /token endpoint using OAuth2.0

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, smart-on-fhir

I am trying to make a FHIR call to a public FHIR server such as SMART Health IT. For that, I have a app that I have hosted using ngrok, and I am launching this app on their server using a custom *client_id* and *client_secret*. I am trying to fetch the access and refresh tokens from their /token endpoint using the below code snippet. However, I am getting the error -

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid launch options: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined"}.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this and make the correct API call?

```
token_endpoint = "https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/auth/token" 

token_request_data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
}
payload = {
    "iss": f"{client_id}",
    "sub": f"{client_id}",
    "aud": f"{token_endpoint}",
    "jti": str(uuid.uuid1()),
    "exp": time.time() + 60*5
}

jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, key=client_secret, algorithm="RS384").decode()
grant_type = 'client_credentials'
client_assertion_type = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer'.replace(':', "%3A")
body = 'grant_type=' + grant_type + '&client_assertion_type=' + client_assertion_type + '&client_assertion=' + jwt_token

token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body, headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

Note that I am using the *requests* library only in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the root cause is you're using the wrong base URL of `https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4`, as no CapabilityStatement is defined there. It appears you're trying to use Back-end OAuth, so your token call should be to `https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/sim/WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ/fhir/auth/token`.

While you're at it, a few other things:

1. Your JWT is missing the required header. Maybe `jwt.encode()` is handling that automatically but if not, the header needs to be present.
2. What's the point of the `token_request_data` object? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere.
3. You're signing the JWT with a client secret. If this is a typical secret like a password, that is incorrect. You should be signing it with a private key from a correctly-generated public-private key pair. (If you'll use the SMART sandbox, it'll need to be the key pair it has already generated.)

Comment: Why is CapabilityStatement needed here? And from where did you get that new URL? Also, just in case it wasn't clear from the question, there is  an app (front-end only) that I have hosted using ngrok. Then, we are using the SMART launcher (https://launch.smarthealthit.org/?tab=1&launch=WzAsIiIsIiIsIkFVVE8iLDAsMCwwLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLDEsMV0&validation=1), and passing the URL of our hosted app as the launch URL. I am also assigning the client ID and client secret here to some values, and I am referencing those values in my code to retrieve the tokens.

Comment: Also, @Ashavan, how can I find the value of `WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ` in the modified URL that you wrote?

Comment: (1/3) The CapabilityStatement is actually at https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/fhir/metadata. However, based on your comment, it's now unclear what you exactly intend to do. Your code shows you creating a JWT, signing it with an RS384 algorithm, and POST-ing directly to the token endpoint. This is indicative of Backend OAuth (https://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/backend-services.html), which is appropriate for a system app that doesn't expect direct user interaction.

Comment: (2/3) But, your comment states you have a front-end only app and that you have a launch URL. This indicates you are actually doing an app launch workflow (either EHR launch or standalone), which would not be compatible with the code you have shared. You should make sure you know exactly what kind of app you intend to build and how it is launched (if at all). Then, you should code towards the appropriate authorization flow for that type of app. The section of the IG for app launch is at https://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/app-launch.html.

Comment: (3/3) And fyi, there is a potentially similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512662/unable-to-retrieve-authorization-code-when-using-oauth2-0-in-python.

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the value of capability statement - WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ ? I did an API call to the endpoint you wrote (metadata), but didn't find this in the response.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "the value of capability statement"? The CapabilityStatement for that particular FHIR server is found at https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/sim/WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ/fhir/metadata. WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ is simply part of the path where the FHIR server that supports Backend OAuth sits.

Comment: But how/where to find the value of WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ? I didn't get this anywhere in the response of the API call made to the capability statement.

Comment: You can see this by going to the SMART Launcher (https://launch.smarthealthit.org/) and changing the launch type to Backend Service. At the bottom, the FHIR server URL will be displayed. This is the URL for the FHIR server that has been configured (for this particular sandbox tool) to simulate and support API call secured by Backend OAuth. The string of WzQsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwwLDAsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsIiIsMCwxXQ is something arbitrarily used by the creators of this sandbox.