# Unable to retrieve authorization code when using OAuth2.0 in Python

Tags: oauth-2.0, python-requests, hl7-fhir

I am trying to make a API call to a public FHIR server (SMART Health IT). I have hosted my application (front-end) using `ngrok` on a server, and I want to fetch the authorization code for it followed by access tokens before retrieving the required data from FHIR. I am launching my app using the SMART Launcher (https://launch.smarthealthit.org/?tab=1&launch=WzAsIiIsIiIsIkFVVE8iLDAsMCwwLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLCIiLDEsMV0&validation=1) and am passing some client id and client secret here. Then, I am trying to use those values in my code to retrieve the authorization code and tokens.

I am using the OAuth2.0 library for python in which I am using the WebApplicationClient to get the authorization URL. However, when I manually go to the authorization URL generated, it redirects to something like

`https://URL/?error=invalid_request&error_description=Invalid+launch+options%3A+SyntaxError%3A+Unexpected+end+of+JSON+input`

Why is this happening? Am I doing anything wrong here? Below is the code I have written. Also, I have no idea how to get the `authorization_response` programmatically in my code (assuming the first problem is solved).

**Note**: `redirect_uri` is the URL of my hosted application on ngrok. It's a pure front-end application.

```
client = WebApplicationClient(client_id)   
authorize_endpoint = "https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/auth/authorize"    
redirect_uri = "https://URL"

authorization_url = client.prepare_request_uri(
  authorize_endpoint,
  redirect_uri = redirect_uri
)
print('Authorization URL: ', authorization_url)

parsed_response = client.parse_request_uri_response(authorization_response)
authorization_code = parsed_response["code"]
```

The above is the portion of code that's causing the error. I am stuck at this step. I am providing the remaining code (below) I have written for reference and context. It assumes the authorization code has been successfully obtained and tries to fetch the access token.

```
data = client.prepare_request_body(
  code = authorization_code,
  redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
  client_id = client_id,
  client_secret = client_secret
)
print('Token data: ', data)
token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

if token_response.status_code == 200:
    access_token = token_response.json()["access_token"]
    print("Access Token:", access_token)
else:
    print("Error obtaining access token:", token_response.text)
```

Comment: Are you intending for your app to be a SMART on FHIR app (i.e., it will be launched directly from an EHR) or a standalone app (i.e., it will be launched from somewhere else, like a smartphone)?

Comment: Also, FYI if you're goal is truly just to "make a API call," as stated, there is no need to go through the authorization flow. The SMART sandbox (base URL = https://r4.smarthealthit.org/) doesn't require any authorization in order to make API calls.

Comment: @Ashavan eventually we want the app to be integrated in an EHR, but for now consider it just to be a web app. It should be able to retrieve data from a public FHIR server(like SMART Health IT), and for that I'm doing this API testing, trying to retrieve authorization code and access tokens.

Regarding the second question, I already have a working prototype with Epic sandbox (without authentication, just directly retrieving tokens), but I wanted to test the API calls by hosting our app on a server and then making the calls. I'll update the question to be more precise about what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you intend for this to be a SMART on FHIR app that is launched from an EHR. In that case, your construction of the authorization URL appears to be incomplete. You have `authorization_url = client.prepare_request_uri(authorize_endpoint, redirect_uri = redirect_uri)`. This would result in an authorization call of `https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/auth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FURL`.

This call is missing...

1. The `launch` parameter, which is set to the launch code provided by the EHR.
2. The `scope` parameter, which defines the scopes needed. Generally this is set to `launch openid fhirUser` but only you will know what's needed ("launch" is required in this scenario).
3. The `aud` parameter, which defines the FHIR server you plan to make calls to. This is provided by the EHR in the `iss` parameter.
4. The `state` parameter, which is arbitrary but used for security reasons.

[The SMART IG's](https://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/app-launch.html#obtain-authorization-code) explanations may be helpful to you. The above info assumes the server you're working with supports the latest iteration of the SMART Implementation Guide. Certain parameters may not be required by your server.